# Dead main repository on github with pull requests

Tags: github

I know really good, but dead project (https://github.com/lusis/lua-httpclient), with some pull requests (bug fixes). Repo owner doesn't look at this requests, last commit was at 2014. I want full version, with all bugfixes.

What is correct action in this situation?  I'm aready have got fork with bugfix.

Comment: Have you tried forking the repo and merging the pull requests on your fork?

Comment: Fork but also contact the maintainer maybe he is fine with adding you as a new maintainer or taking over.

Comment: Helpful info and discussion on that issue: https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/756

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the project really is dead (not being maintained/monitored at all) you can fork it, then contact the contributors that submitted the bug fixes/pull requests and make sure they don't have a problem with you including their code in your forked copy.

They'll probably be happy that you are continuing the project, if it's something they contributed to. Getting in contact with them will also let them know that the project is alive (if forked) which may motivate them to continue to contribute.

Comment: It would be great if we could fork a repo with all pending pull requests at once and then merge easily... not possible yet.